# Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS unable to install postgresql(-client)-13 or above (WSL)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, apt-get

sry but I am not an expert on Linux/Ubuntu, I just use WSL and zsh to fiddle around with it a bit and now for a dev project I need postgre-client-13, 12 seems to be included in Ubuntu focal, but I can not use that, as I need to make DB backups with pg_dump and that gives me a version error then.

I tried literally every SF and Blog Post I could find, but it always came done to versions of this in the end:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-15 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-client-15 : Depends: libpq5 (>= 15.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 is to be installed
                        Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Currently i deinstalled psql with apt-get purge, but now I have the problem that I can not even install version 12 of it anymore, guess with copying some scripts I broke my global Ubuntu config, now even just calling

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

leads just to:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-client : Depends: postgresql-client-15 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried reading into the problem of held packages, but that is still a bit over my head.
Can someone point me to a good ressource or the right direction to fix my problem? I guess one could be restoring/updating the list of package versions an Ubunut version includes/supports, at least I read something about this?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: `Depends: libssl3`?  Does Ubuntu 20.04 even support `libssl3`?  I'm guessing not.

Comment: Yeah mate, that was the problem, wow, instead of looking at threads and blogs for hours, I should have just updated my Ubuntu version and all would have been fine and dandy, thanks